# Ubuntu 11.10 starts in a strange mode

Tags: ubuntu, path, ubuntu-11.10

I removed Maven2 from my computer and tried installing Maven3. While doing this I added a few things to the /etc/environment file, as instructed by the Maven guys. Anyway, after a few successful log-outs, I logged-out again and suddenly was not be able to log in back, even after booting and shutting down my laptop.

When Ubuntu starts it asks for my password and then I see a blank screen with numbers on the top left and "dwm-5.8.2" on the top right (see images). The only thing I can do is access the command line (ctrl-alt-F2). I did that and modified my /etc/environment file back to the original, but still got the same screen after reboot. When I select the guest user everything starts normally.

I have no idea what's going on. Thanks for your help!

Images:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please answer your own question once you can (another 2 hrs), there's no real point putting the solution into the question. Just use the **answer your question** button below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your desktop looks a lot like the background of the ubuntu session manager i see on :
http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/10/17/guest-session-and-user-management-in-ubuntu-11-10/

something that has been set for your user is crashing the Unity system and apparently the fallback is to dwm, which is apparently a component of ubuntus session manager (dynamic window manager).  I would guess the numbers are for virtual desktops.

try logging in as yourself and from terminal doing 'sudo apt-get reinstall unity' or 'sudo apt-get install xfce' or similar (use search engines to find precisely correct commands).

if that does not work something that unity doesn't require has been accidentally changed by you or a third party.